# Mongoose .populate not showing in JSON

Tags: node.js, json, express, mongoose

I have some code which populates a section called "user". When I console.log the result I get a nicely filled document like this:

```
[ { _id: 60f92778ceefc423d834d9c0,
title: 'Vaatwasser',
day: 0,
house: '60f455b1e0394e12a226045a',
user: { _id: 60f4142ff55f81251a7224ff, name: 'Lucas Blommers' },
createdAt: 2021-07-22T08:08:24.477Z,
updatedAt: 2021-07-22T08:08:24.477Z,
__v: 0 },
{ _id: 60f92788ceefc423d834d9c3,
title: 'Koken',
day: 0,
house: '60f455b1e0394e12a226045a',
user: { _id: 60f4142ff55f81251a7224ff, name: 'Lucas Blommers' },
createdAt: 2021-07-22T08:08:40.712Z,
updatedAt: 2021-07-22T08:08:40.712Z,
__v: 0 } ]
```

But when I request the data using Android or Postman I get the following result:

```
{
        "_id": "60f92778ceefc423d834d9c0",
        "title": "Vaatwasser",
        "day": 0,
        "house": "60f455b1e0394e12a226045a",
        "user": {},
        "createdAt": "2021-07-22T08:08:24.477Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-07-22T08:08:24.477Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

As you can see the user is an empty object after it gets send.
Is this a bug in the JSON library or am I doing something wrong on the server.

-Edit-
Here's the server side code:

```
const housekeepings = await Housekeeping.find({day:day, house: 
house}).populate("user", "name")
                                
console.log(housekeepings)

return res.send(housekeepings)
```

Comment: You can try `await Housekeeping.find({day:day, house: house}).populate("user", "name").lean()`

Answer (score 1):

"You can try await Housekeeping.find({day:day, house: house}).populate("user", "name").lean() – Cuong Le Ngoc"

This is the answer. Thank you very much Cuong.